# Flutter Freezed generated files differently from machine to machine

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed, flutter-freezed, build-runner

[image: IMPL vs NOT]

This image shows the issue.

When i run the same codebase 'build' in one machine i get one diff, and backwards on a diff machine. Any ideas?

I tried removing all the project from the machine and downloading again. Nothing.